# How to remove all commits from last push in git, when you mixed two different repos?

Tags: git

I have one GIT repository (A), which has commits old more then two years, then there is different repository (B), which has commits like one year old.

Not what happened, when setting up B's repository origin, there was a mistake and it lead to repository A, after push there are all commits from repository B in the repository A.

Is there a way how to remove these commits?

I should say as well that there are mixed commits in time, so I can't easily reset to commit, because it would reset all the commits from repository A, is that right?

Comment: Do the commits from A and B share any common ancestors?

Comment: No they are completely seperated. As you can see on this graph https://github.com/ufik/WebCMS2/network the black one should not be there.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you want master to be pointing to [fb7e4a4](https://github.com/ufik/WebCMS2/commit/fb7e4a473454b6dafb2d99f410e12f57d7db8d08), and that all commits in the path between [57ae6ccff](https://github.com/ufik/WebCMS2/commit/57ae6ccff8f33b66e4c588821e163882a61acdf5) and the current position of master should be removed (or at least made unreachable)?

Comment: Well basically yes, but not all the commits, because there are also commits from branch A, which were correct.

Comment: There should be no need to actually remove any commits; all you need to do is `git checkout master; git reset --hard fb7e4a4; git push --force-with-lease <your remote> master`. Any commits that need to be kept will be kept, and any commits that don't belong in the history will be garbage-collected eventually by GitHub.

Comment: heh, very nice my friend :) Can you write this solution as an answer, bounty is yours!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99312/discussion-between-tavnab-and-tom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all your desired commits are intact and `master` was just moved, there should be no need to actually remove any commits; all you need to do is put master back where it was before the push:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit SHA-1 of where you want master to be>
git push --force-with-lease <your remote> master
```

Any commits that need to be kept (i.e. because they were already part of the 'good' master's history) will be kept, and any commits that don't belong in the history will be garbage-collected eventually by GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Several options:

1. #### Git reset to a given commit

   ```
   # This will destroy any local modifications.
   # Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
   git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
   ```
2. #### checkout the last desired

   ```
   git checkout -b <new_branch> <commit id>

   // Now your branch contains all the commits up to the 
   // desired one and without the newer ones
   ```
3. #### `git revert`

   git revert will allow you to rollback any commit, what you need to do is to make a list of all the commits in A which you want to remove (with script) and then revert them from the second repository

   ```
   git revert <commit1> <commit2> ... <commitn>
   ```
4. #### `filter-branch`

   Use this option to completely remove the commits from the history.

   ```
   git filter-branch --commit-filter '
       if [ `git rev-list --all --grep "<log-pattern>" | grep -c "$GIT_COMMIT"` -gt 0 ]
       then
           skip_commit "$@";
       else
           git commit-tree "$@";
       fi'  
   HEAD
   ```

Comment: I don't think reset will help, because if I made commits on 1st of December to both of them and I want to go to the stage on the 1st of November, it would delete the commit to repository A (1st of December), right?

Comment: Saw your update after i answered. ill update my answer to be more correct based upon your limitations.

Comment: Ok, but revert will keep those files in the history, right? It will just create a new commit, with reverted operation. What if I want to completely remove this mistake from the history?

Comment: In order to compltley remove the commits you will need to use `filter-branch` which is a bit more complicated but it will do the work

Comment: Can you explain little bit what will the last option do, please?

Comment: Sure. filter branch loop on all the commits in the branch and for each commit you "take" it or "drop" it, This is what the script does.

Comment: Ok so I need to manually say, this commit will stay and this one will be deleted? If so, it might be a problem as there are hundreds of commits. But still I can do that programmatically, what about that rebase option?

Comment: Of course it will be in a script.. unless you have a full year of doing it manually :-). using rebase you will need to do it manually.

Comment: Okay, I am just not familiar with `git rev-list --all --grep "<log-pattern>" for instance and how can I use all this in a script.

Comment: Read a bit about it. you can change the script to check the date of the commit, the author or any other piece of info that you need.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help. I will try to fix this issue and will accept one of the answers afterwards.

Comment: Well I have tried the last solution and it doesn't work. I've tried to put commit message which was repeated many times in some commits instead of <log-pattern> and it will not remove those commits, it will rather add some new commits instead :/

Here is the prove, if I call this command before and after
git rev-list --all | wc -l

it will return after higher number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with`git rebase -i <commit>`. Where `<commit>` will be the parent of the commit where you make the commits from repository (A) started. Then select the commits you would like to change marking them as `pick`. If you like to remove a commit mark it as `delete`. Each picked commit will be checked out and you will be able to edit the commit there by doing `git commit --amend`.

Comment: I don't really follow the second sentence, do you mean that should be the first commit from repository B, which I pushed to repository A? To remove all of them?

Answer (score 0):

When you push branch from unrelated repository, their commits do not mix. You either get a new branch or completely replace the existing one:

1) if you did not have branch with same name in A, then you simply create a new branch, which does not contain any A commits:

```
-(B1)-(B2)-..-(BM) <--- branchB
```

Such branches can be simply removed.

2) if A and B have branches with same name, then it's *completely* replaced:

```
-(A1)-(A2)-(A3)-(A4)-..-(AN) <--- branch (rewritten)

-(B1)-(B2)-..-(BM) <--- branch
```

This is harder to fix - you should find the last point of the branch which contained A files. It it was not long time ago, it is possible to do with `git reflog` command. You can also use the command to sort out case 1 from case 2.

(The only way to mix the commits is to commit files from A over a commit from B after the wrong push:

```
-(B1)-(B2)-..-(BM)-(A)!!!
```

But such change would be removing all files from B and adding all files from A, and you would notice it at committing, so I assume such thing did not happen)

So, to fix things, you scan though all branches which are currently in A, and check if it contains A or B files (with `git ls-files _branch_`). Then for each B branch run `git reflog _branch_`. If it contains only 1 line `_hash_ _branch_@{0}: push` - it is B-only branch and can be removed. If it is longer, then call `git ls-files _hash_` for each line, to find the last commit which still had the A files. When you find it run `git branch -f _branch_ _hash_` to reset the branch to that hash.

PS: It would be good to read first 3 chapters of http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. These two repos have indeed same branch name (master), but it wasn't replaced, I can see all commits from A and B as well, if I take a look into the git tree I can even see that these two branches are not mixed. Take a look here (https://github.com/ufik/WebCMS2/network) the black branch line is from B branch which should not be there.